# prime factorization of values of $(n+a_1)(n+a_2)\cdots(n+a_9)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

For the 9 distinct positive integers $a_1$, $a_2$, ..., $a_9$, we look at the polynomial
$$p(n) = (n+a_1)(n+a_2)\cdots(n+a_9).$$
Prove that for any $a_1,a_2,\dots, a_9$, there exists a number $N$ for which for all numbers $p(n)$ with $n\ge N$ have a prime factor greater than $20$.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? What is the context of the problem? If related to a course, what tools are you supposed to be using?

Comment: Nah, it is just an olympiade style question. I tried to proof it by contradiction by assuming that $p(n>=N)=2^(e_1) * 3^(e_2) * 5^(e_3) + ... + 19^(e_4) 
But I wasn't able to solve it that way, maybe somebody else can

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve this but I think it's worth to note that the 9th prime is 23. So a good place to start is the pigeonhole principle.